# Call function every time I add 'ManyRelatedObject'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm making a pizza application and the task is I have a different price for different size of pizza. And also, if I add a topping to pizza, the price gets bigger.

I have a set_price function that sets the price for pizza. What I need to do is to call this set_price function every time I add a new topping and every time I create a new pizza object.

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

class RegPizza(models.Model):
    size = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    price = 0
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping, blank=True, related_name="inreg")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Regular Pizza ({self.price}$)"

    def set_price(self):
        if self.size == 'Small':
            self.price = 12.20
            if self.toppings.count() == 1:
                self.price = 13.20
            if self.toppings.count() == 2:
                self.price = 14.70
            if self.toppings.count() == 3:
                self.price = 15.70
        if self.size == 'Large':
            self.price = 17.45
            if self.toppings.count() == 1:
                self.price = 19.45
            if self.toppings.count() == 2:
                self.price = 21.45
            if self.toppings.count() == 3:
                self.price = 23.45
```

Comment: YOu don't need a price field at all. Simply calculate the figure at display time. Don't store it in the database because the usual practice is not to store the result of simple caclulations in the database.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I should remove ‘size’ too because I needed it only to change the price field

Comment: No you wil need the size

Comment: The price is dependent on the size and the toppings, s you need to have both those items of data but since price is a dependent variable, that's the only one that should not be saved

Comment: Agree with above comments. Rename `set_price` to `price` and simply `return` the calculated price instead of setting it to an instance attribute. You may also consider making this a `@property`. If this is a real life application (i.e. not a class assignment or an experiment) I would also suggest you to store prices in the database too. You don't want to make code changes every time a price change.